# java microsoft sql server 2012 connection

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2012

Help!!! I've tried everything but none is working. I've also tried //., //local:1433, etcetc...

Thank you in advance. Here's my connection:

[image: COnnection]

**Proof of me enabling TCP/IP:**

[image]

I don't think code is needed just for connecting besides these 2 lines:

```
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

This is my connection string:

```
    DBConnect dbc = new DBConnect("jdbc:sqlserver://KEN;databaseName=JavaCS349;integratedSecurity=true");
```

Here's the error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host KEN, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
>       at DBConnect.(DBConnect.java:25)
>       at DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:40)

Comment: _Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall_ Did you check this too? And verified that the SQL Server service is started?

Comment: I just write code, don't know anything about network or firewalls. I just know firewall is on default mode and I've never touched it. Should I turn off firewall completely? and yes, sql server management studio was running. It's connecting fine in my asp.net project too.

Comment: ok, I just followed this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx#SSMSProcedure  and still receiving same error.

Comment: Check if SQL Server is configured on a **fixed port number**, since SQL Server 2005 (I believe), the default config is dynamic port, which requires the SQL Server browsing service to be running to connect, otherwise you need to configure an explicit port.

Comment: In the SQL Server Configuration Manager under "SQL Server Services" make sure that the SQL Server Browser service is running.

Comment: Thank you so much. SQL Server Services was disabled on default.